# Is the characteristic function of a product of two random variables unique?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, products, characteristic-functions

Consider a random variable $X$ with distribution function F (write, $X \sim F$) and a random variable $Y$ with distribution function $G$ (write, $Y \sim G$).

Now, we can find the characteristic function of $W = XY$ by

\begin{equation}
\phi_{W}(t)=E[\exp (\mathrm{i} t W)]=E[\exp (\mathrm{i} t X Y)]=E\{E[\exp (\mathrm{i} t X Y) \mid Y]\}
\end{equation}

My question is then: does the characteristic function $\phi_{W}(t)$ uniquely define the distribution of $W$ similarly to how the characteristic function of X, (say, $\phi_{X}(t)$) would uniquely define the distribution of the random variable $X$?

Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, the characteristic function is well defined. Its definition is $\phi_W(t) = E(e^{itW}).$ When you expand out the definition, you will encounter $\int e^{itw} f_W(w) dw.$ _However,_ there is a powerful theorem that states that if $W$ is a function of $(X, Y),$ say $W = g(X, Y),$ then $E(W) = \int g(x, y) f_{X,Y}(x,y) d(x,y).$ So, what you have is that $\phi_W(t) = \int\limits_{\mathbf{R}^2} e^{i t xy} f_{X,Y} (x,y)d(x,y).$

Answer (score 1):

**I am going to explain using densities, the general case has the same gist. This was meant to be a comment but too long.**

First, I suppose you understand that the c.f. of a random variable determines the distribution of said r.v. (in other words, if $X_1$ and $X_2$ have the same distribution then $\phi_{X_1} = \phi_{X_2}$). You are probably confused as what the distribution of $W$ is since many different random variables $X$ and $Y$ have the prespecified distributions $f_X$ and $f_Y.$ To understand what the distribution of $W$ is you need to first give the distribution for the joint vector $(X, Y)$ and then find the distributions of $W = XY$ using the joint distribution. When $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then the joint distribution *must be* $f_{X, Y}(x,y) = f_X(x) f_Y(y)$ and you are done. Otherwise you need to specify $f_{X, Y}.$ Notice that specifying $f_{X,Y}$ gives the distributions $f_X$ and $f_Y$ (by integrating against the other variable) but the reverse is *never true* besides the independent case. I hope this helps.